# Should I use an N-channel or a P-channel MOSFET in a coil gun?

Tags: mosfet, coil, spike

With an N-channel MOSFET, the coil is located between Vcc and drain so when the MOSFET switches off the coil has to create a big voltage spike because it has to overcome the MOSFET.

Is that problem eliminated with a P-channel MOSFET? The coil is located between drain and ground and it doesn't have to overcome any resistance.

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make a lot of sense to me, you still have Rds resistance with a P-channel MOSFET. If your design allows you to use a low-side switch, then an N-channel MOSFET is usually the best option.

Comment: you must apply a suitable flywheel diode (normally reverse biased) in parallel to the coil.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when the n-channel mosfet switches off, the coil will create a big voltage spike. But this will not overcome the mosfet in a proper designed circuit (or the mosfet would be damaged).

The coil does not care if you switch it off/on to GND with a n-channel mosfet or if you switch it off/on to VCC with a p-channel mosfet. It is exactly a symmetrical situation.

The only difference is that the n-channel mosfets are typically a bit faster in switching than the p-channel types (because electrons have higher mobility than holes).

Comment: nitpick: because electrons have higher mobility than holes in common semiconductors. I believe there are some exotic semiconductors where hole mobility is higher.

Comment: @Hearth Indeed, some thoughts here: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_is_the_mobility_of_electron_higher_than_that_of_hole